# How to find $\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty} \frac{F_n}{3^n}$

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

How can I find $$\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty} \frac{F_n}{3^n}$$ If I know that the generating function for the Fibonacci sequence is $G(t) = \frac{t}{1 - t - t^2}$?

Comment: Hint: You have $G(t) =\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{F_n}{t^n}$. What happens if you evaluate this at $t=1$? At $t=\dfrac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{3^n}t^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n\left(\frac{t}{3}\right)^n = G(t/3)
$$